# cakephp - auth logout redirect

Tags: redirect, authentication, cakephp-2.0, logout

In cakephp2.0, I have **domain.com** but when I logout (url is **domain.com/logout**), it is redirected to **domain.com/app/login**. I dont want it to redirect to **domain.com/app/login** but instead redirect to **domain.com/logout**. These are the codes I have in my UsersController & my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Session');

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
         'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    )
);
}
```

**Userscontroller**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
public $components = array(

    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
         'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout', 'login');
    $this->Auth->deny('view');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->redirect('http://domain.com/thankyou');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this in my logout() function

```
$this->Auth->logout();
$this->redirect(some url);
```

Comment: Now, with CakePHP 4.1 it is `$this->Authentication->logout();`

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a view for the logout page? Something that you are trying to display after they are logged out? What might be happening is that the user is logged out, but Cake is unable to display the logout page because it is secure, so Cake redirects to the login page.

If you have security enabled and a page you want to be displayed to a user that is not logged in, you will need to include something like this in its controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that ?

```
'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
)
```

And

```
public function logout() {
    //$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    //Change for :
    //I suppose that you have a logout.ctp view in your View/Pages
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'logout')
}
```

Then in your rootes

```
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'logout'));
```

of course don't forget

```
$this->Auth->allow('display'
```